# If $a \sin \alpha = b \sin \beta$, then show that $ b \cot\alpha + a \cot \beta = (a+b)\cot \frac{\alpha +\beta}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

The question is:

> If $a \sin \alpha = b \sin \beta$, then show that
>   $$
> b \cot\alpha + a \cot \beta = (a+b)\cot \frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}
> $$

Could I get any hints to the problem? When do I need to apply the formula(e) for compound angles? I got stuck when I tried to expand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\dfrac a{\sin\beta}=\dfrac b{\sin\alpha}=\dfrac{a+b}{\sin\beta+\sin\alpha}$$

Now $b\cot\alpha+a\cot\beta=\cos\alpha\cdot\dfrac b{\sin\alpha}+\cos\beta\cdot\dfrac a{\sin\beta}$

Replace $\dfrac a{\sin\beta},\dfrac b{\sin\alpha}$ with $\dfrac{a+b}{\sin\beta+\sin\alpha}$

and use [Prosthaphaeresis Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html)

Comment: This is the most elegant solution. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: $\dfrac{a}{b} = \dfrac{\sin \beta}{\sin \alpha}$, and divide both sides by $b$ and use the above substitution to deduce the equation.

Comment: Okay, I got $$\frac{2\cos(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2})\cos(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2})}{\sin\alpha}$$. Now what?

Answer (score 0):

A careful substitution will give you the required results. It took me 3minutes using trigonometric properties.

Check those from this site [here](http://www.sosmath.com/trig/Trig5/trig5/trig5.html)